# TCPROS/UDPROS Jumbogram support in IPV6 for lower latency high bandwidth communications

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Supporters,

Why is a ROS UDP Datagram support limited to a block size under 2K? TCP/IP v4 supports a Datagram up to 65535, while IPv6 supports TCPIP, and UDP Jumbogram up to 4GB. It seems that the video latency due to increased CPU processing, and network message bandwidth decrement justifies larger UDP block sizes?

Any constructive input will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124781/tcpros/udpros-jumbogram-support-in-ipv6-for-lower-latency-high-bandwidth-communications/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The protocol can support those larger block sizes, however you need to pick the lowest common denominator for what will be supported by the network devices such as routers etc. There's a lot of older hardware without super large MTU support. And also very large packets do not work well over wireless which is one of the primary reasons for using the lower latency UDP. Picking the size is always a tradeoff. It will help larger data get through with lower latency, but will actually slow down delivery of small packets, either by blocking the network or batching them depending on the choice of protocol.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0